# Calculating the volume of a hemisphere given only the height

Tags: volume

So I have a math problem that I'm trying to solve with regards to hemispheres but am just confused about this part of the question

If I have a hemisphere with radius $r$, then

> Volume $= \frac23\pi r^3$

However, how can I find some volume within the hemisphere if I am given the height only?

I've only used height of a hemisphere when I know it is equal to the radius but never less.

Thank you!

Comment: height $= 2 r$.

Comment: A hemisphere is half of a sphere, which is not what you want, I think.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're talking about a [spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap).

If so, the volume of a spherical cap with height $h$ on a sphere with radius $r$ is
$$
V = \frac{\pi h^2}{3}(3r - h)
$$